# TikZ customize default

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to customize the default settings of **tikzpicture**.

Usually I use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.center)}]
....
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to set the options `[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.center)}]` at the beginning of the document or better in the my theme's configurations file once and just use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
....
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a strange thing to do, but:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={overlay,remember picture,shift={(current page.center)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{Foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{Bar};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```